# Who is holding the strong reference to IBOutlet in XIB custom view, to prevent deallocation?

Tags: ios, swift

I can understand why an `IBOutlet` for a `UIViewController` from XIB can be weak.

As, `UIViewController` holds strong reference to `UIView`, and `UIView` holds strong reference to `IBOutlet`.

```
UIViewController -> UIView -> IBOutlet
```

However, I notice that if I create a custom `UIView` from XIB.

```
class ColorPickerActionSheet: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var customButton: UIButton!
```

Thing works fine even if I use weak for the IBOutlet in custom view.

Since the custom view (`ColorPickerActionSheet`  in the above case) is not holding a strong reference to `IBOutlet`. I was wondering, who is holding the strong reference to `IBOutlet`, to prevent deallocation?

Comment: You have some misconceptions. A view controller holds a strong reference to it's content view. It also has references to other views that it needs to access through code. These are labeled with the tag `@IBOutlet`, but they are really just instance variables. The `@IBOutlet` tag lets Xcode recognize them as intended for linking instance variables for view objects to the views in their XIB or storyboard. (As explained in Tarun's excellent answer.)

Comment: IBOutlets are usually weak references. What keeps your view controller's views alive is the fact that a view's superview holds a strong reference to it. If your remove a view from it's superview, it will get deallocated unless you keep another strong reference to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your question, there is a view hierarchy, where each view maintains an array of its immediate [`subviews`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622614-subviews) (i.e., each view keeps a strong reference to its subviews). And if those subviews have subviews of their own, they will respectively keep strong references to those. Thus, view hierarchy alone establishes all the necessary strong references to all the subviews (and their subviews, etc.). If we [debug the view hierarchy](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html) by pausing the execution, I can see this hierarchy:

[image]

Here we see a complete view hierarchy independent of any `@IBOutlet` references that may or may not have been added. The button has a strong reference in the view hierarchy, completely independent of whether an `@IBOutlet` was defined for that particular control/view or not.

In short, `@IBOutlet` references are not for dictating ownership, but rather are just convenient references to these objects that are already contained with view hierarchy.

---

As a general rule, if you ever have a question about where the strong references are, tap on the “debug memory graph” button (discussed in [Gathering Information About Memory Use](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/gathering-information-about-memory-use#see-also)). In this case, going through the memory graphs for these buttons are likely to be less fruitful than just looking at the view hierarchy.

Comment: Rob, your answer got cut off mid-sentence.

Comment: That's the problem when I try to multitask while posting answers on S.O. Lol.

Answer (score 2):

When your XIB's XML source code is decoded and brought into memory as `UIView` instance (along with all it's subviews, other elements), your IBOutlet variables are populated with correct values by the decoder.

As long as your view lives in memory (by being attached to it's superview OR by being held into a strong variable while not being in view hierarchy) - all of it's subviews are guaranteed to exist and hence all the IBOutlet variables keep referencing those existing elements.

The point is - if your view is on screen - it's parent (superview) is retaining it making sure it lives in memory and this hierarchy goes down to every level in view hierarchy.